# UWP: How to create a flipView with multiple items in the view port?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to create a UI element similar to this [image]

I looked at possible controls and it looks like flipView might be the closest approximation. By default, FlipView only shows 1 element in the viewport and you have to click on chevron to move between different items. However, I want to have multiple items say 4-5 and after which I can use the chevron to move back and forth.

```html
<Grid>
        <FlipView Height="700" Width="800">
            <Grid Margin="0 0 300 0" >
                <Image 
                    Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Image.jpg"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Margin="-200,0,200,0">
                <Image 
                    Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Image.jpg"
                    />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Margin="-200,0,200,0">
                <Image 
                    Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Image.jpg"
                    />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Margin="-200,0,200,0">
                <Image 
                    Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Image.jpg"
                   />
            </Grid>
        </FlipView>
</Grid>
```

I could get everything other than the first image show up.
Is there a better way to do this? Or a better control than flip view?

Comment: The control from the Store is not implemented using FlipView. It's a customized control.  As @Andrew said that you could try the Carousel control from the Community Toolkit. Also, you could try to full customize a control on your own to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Carousel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/carousel) control from the **Windows Community Toolkit** is a good control for this kind of UI.